# Custom Frame is not accepting Height Request in MAUI

Tags: frame, maui

I am converting my Xamarin Forms Application to .NET MAUI.

I am trying to migrate the Custom renderer from Xamarin to MAUI following this link [Using Custom Renderers in .NET MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI)

Here is my Code:

```
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMauiCompatibility()
             .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
             {
                 handlers.AddCompatibilityRenderer(typeof(CustomFrame), typeof(CustomShadowFrameRenderer));
             });
            
        return builder.Build();
    }
```

CustomFrame:

```
public class CustomFrame : Frame
    {
        public CustomFrame()
        {
            
        }
       
    }
```

Below is the Custom Renderer Class

```
 public class CustomShadowFrameRenderer : FrameRenderer
    {

        public CustomShadowFrameRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != null && e.OldElement == null)
            {
                e.NewElement.HeightRequest = 1000;
                e.NewElement.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            }
        }
```

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage" BackgroundColor="Red"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.Controls">
    <local:CustomFrame BackgroundColor="Blue" HeightRequest="1000" Padding="20">
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </local:CustomFrame>
</ContentPage>
```

The Frame is not accepting the height Request in MAUI but the same works fine in Xamarin forms.

Below is the image for the same

[image]

Comment: I don't know why that does not work, but is there a reason not to set those Element properties within the custom frame's code behind? Also, consider migrating from Frame to Maui's `Border` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a sample to test your code and met the same problem. In addition, I even can't click the button in the CustomFrmae. It seems there are some compatibility issues about the FrameRender in the maui.

So I try to change the CustomRender to the CustomHandler. It worked well and you just need to change two place code.

1. In the CustomShadowFrameRenderer class, make it such as `public class CustomShadowFrameRenderer : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer`
2. In the MauiProgram.cs:

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
             .UseMauiApp<App>()
             .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
             {
                  handlers.AddHandler(typeof(CustomFrame), typeof(CustomShadowFrameRenderer));        
             })
```